# Can I manually manage resolution of requires at run time with webpack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson, webpack

I want to be able to:

1. Load a module and assign it into the namespace:

```
$.GET("http://path.to.my/library").then(function(jsSourceCode){
    return webpack_load('myLibrary', jsSourceCode);
}).then(function(){
    var myLibrary = require('myLibrary');
    ... do stuff;
});
```

2. Unload a module:

```
$.GET("http://path.to.my/library").then(function(jsSourceCode){
    return webpack_load('myLibrary', jsSourceCode);
}).then(function(){
    var myLibrary = require('myLibrary');
    ... do stuff;
    webpack_unload('myLibrary');
});
```

3. Change a modules name:

```
if (webpack_isLoaded('react')){
    webpack_rename('react-0.12', 'react');
}
webpack_load('react', newReactSourceCode);
```

But I want to be able to do this from the console (i.e. at run time after the compile). How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to do this via browser console ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek yes, pretty much

Answer (score 0):

The browser console issue is that you can only acess public ( global ) variables , anyway what you are trying yo do here should be pretty easy .

**Solution :**

- Assign a global variable for your function like :

  var load_module=function (){
  //your load module code here
  }

make sure this variable has a global scope.

- Open your browser console and call your function , type the code in console window :

  load_module();

and that is it , repeat this for rest of functions.